# IP address conflicts and Router Issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I Have the following situation at home:

I own a laptop/notebook PC  and my brother has a desktop PC.
We both are connected to the internet via Netgear WiFi router which is connected to 2Mb/s ADSL (the fastest possible in my area).

I am particularly fond of playing SWTOR (Star Wars: The Old Republic) which is a MMORPG. Unfortunately every time I start playing, the desktop PC detects IP address conflict and disconnects him from the network. Often it disconnects without detecting the IP conflict. Occasionally both of us get disconnected from the network

Can anyone identify the issue and suggest how I can rectify it?

Comment: Ate your computers getting IPs via DHCP?

Comment: @BigChris I believe so

Comment: Does your game change any IP settings of your computer? I would think not, but it's worth asking...

Although this is highly unlikely, but have either of your computers accidentally got a static IP configured? Do `ipconfig /all` and see if it says "assigned by DHCP" for your network adapters.

Comment: @BigChris Yes all adapters have DCHP enabled.

Comment: Is everything OK when another computer's cable is unplugged?

Comment: @Jet We both are connected via WiFi

Comment: You say "My brother's PC detects a IP address conflict and disconnects him from the network"  Firstly it's just another computer, the fact that it's your brother's is not relevant to the computer problem you are having. Secondly, state the exact error message (that way it's googlable).

Comment: and so are you able to both browse the internet at the same time, then you launch up the game and suddenly bam that error (I ask to help anybody get to the nub of whatever the problem is)

Comment: @Matthew I mean is everything OK when another PC is disconnected (before starting the game)?

Comment: @barlop Yes browsing the internet on multiple PC and/or mobile devices causes no IP address conflicts. As you say " I  launch up the game and suddenly bam that error" I have been notified that most of the time no error message appear and It simply "kicks" the desktop off the subnet

Comment: @Jet Yes, When the other PC is disconnected no errors occur.

Comment: @Matthew ok and as I said, it does help to have the exact wording of the message in quotes.

Comment: @barlop When the error message appears. The following appears: Another computer on this network has the same IP address as this computer. Contact your network administrator for help resolving this issue. More details are available in the Windows System event log

Comment: Can you tell us IPs? (before and after problem)

Comment: Have got any address reservations on your router that you've overlooked or are within the DHCP pool?

Comment: @BigChris How would I check this?

Comment: @Matthew well it's pretty much the first thing you check. open a cmd prompt and do ipconfig>ENTER> and it'll look like `192...` or `10... `   It will say  `IPv4(or just IP) Address. . .. . : 192.x.y.z`   And write what it says. Check if the computers are really the same IP. In which case you shouldn't be surprised you got that error

Comment: -1 for abandoning your question and not replying to requests for info.  So the question and its answer are then not that useful for somebody with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for any devices on your network that have a static IP, which could then be interfering with your IP.

You could also try changing the scope of your routers DHCP ser from say 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 to 192.168.100.1-192.168.100.255.

Comment: The router scope is 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254.

Comment: @Matthew so you know that and 10min later you ask how to find your computer's IP. interesting.

Comment: @barlop I apologize I misread your question

Comment: @Matthew You misread it yesterday, now you say you misread it, but you still haven't answered it. Please if you reply to me, give a response with content. i.e. if you are to respond to me, I suggest you either answer the question, or state why you are having difficulty answering the question. Otherwise it's just not useful or informative and is just white noise.